# Print escaped color characters to bash

Tags: c, bash, readline

I'm using the readline library in C to create a bash-like prompt within bash. When I tried to make the prompt colorful, with color sequences like [these](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/bash-prompt-escape-sequences.html), the coloring works great, but the cursor spacing is messed up. The input is wrapped around too early and the wrap-around is to the same line so it starts overwriting the prompt. I thought I should escape the color-sequences with `\[` and `\]` like

`readline("\[\e[1;31m$\e[0m\] ")`

But that prints the square brackets, and if I escape the backslashes it prints those too. How do I escape the color codes so the cursor still works?

Comment: Escaping sequences like that is a Bash-specific thing. If you print from a program you don't need the surrounding brackets. Also note that the sequence `"\e"` is an extension in the GCC compiler, it's not generally portable.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, I mean that the `"\["` and `"\]"` pair is Bash-specific, and you don't need it.

Comment: Have you tried `readline("\[\033[1;31m$\033[0m\] ")`? `\033` instead of `\e`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to tell readline that a character sequence in a prompt string doesn't actually move the cursor when output to the screen is to surround it with the markers `RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE` (currently, this is the character literal '\001' in readline's C header file) and `RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE` (currently '\002').

And as @Joachim and @Alter said, use '\033' instead of '\e' for portability.

Answer (score 2):

I found this question when looking to refine the GNU readline prompt **in a bash script**. Like readline in C code, `\[` and `\]` aren't special but `\001` and `\002` will work *when given literally* via the special treatment bash affords quoted words of the form `$'string'`.  I've been here before (and left unsatisfied due to not knowing to combine it with `$'…'`), so I figured I'd leave my explanation here now that I have a solution.

Using the data provided here, I was able to conclude this result:

```bash
C1=$'\001\033[1;34m\002'   # blue   -  from \e[1;34m
C0=$'\001\033[0;0m\002'    # reset  -  from \e[0;0m
while read -p "${C1}myshell>$C0 " -e command; do
  echo "you said: $command"
done
```

This gives a blue prompt that says `myshell>` and has a trailing space, without colors for the actual command.  Neither hitting <kbd>Up</kbd> nor entering a command that wraps to the next line will be confused by the non-printing characters.

As explained in the accepted answer, `\001` ([Start of Heading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#SOH)) and `\002` ([Start of Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#STX)) are the `RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE` and `RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE` markers, which tell bash and readline not to count anything between them for the purpose of painting the terminal.  (Also found here: `\033` is more reliable than `\e` and since I'm now using octal codes anyway, I might as well use one more.)

There seems to be quite the dearth of documentation on this; the best I could find was in perl's documentation for [Term::ReadLine::Gnu](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term::ReadLine::Gnu#readline-PROMPT-PREPUT), which says:

> `PROMPT` may include some escape sequences. Use `RL_PROMPT_START_IGNORE` to begin a sequence of non-printing characters, and `RL_PROMPT_END_IGNORE` to end the sequence.